# String null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

i have some strange NullPointerException at my app.

I run this code:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
{               

    Log.i("name1", userProfilePictures[positionForPicture][0]);

    if(movedToAnotherActivity)
        return;

    if(loadNewPosts && loaded10More == false)
    {           
        firstLoopPicture = true;
        positionForPicture = 0;
        return; 
    }

    if((positionForPicture  == userProfilePictures.length) == false)
    {
        new GetUserPicture().execute();

        int loadLength = loadedPostsSaverForPictures.length;

        String name = userProfilePictures[positionForPicture][0];

        Log.i("name", name);
    }
}
```

...
...
...

And i get null pointer exception at this line:

```
String name = userProfilePictures[positionForPicture][0];
    Log.i("name", name);
```

Log cat:

```
08-28 17:39:28.140: E/AndroidRuntime(26801): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-28 17:39:28.140: E/AndroidRuntime(26801): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
08-28 17:39:28.140: E/AndroidRuntime(26801):    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
08-28 17:39:28.140: E/AndroidRuntime(26801):    at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:159)
08-28 17:39:28.140: E/AndroidRuntime(26801):    at com.example.workoutlog.WorkoutsWall$GetUserPicture.onPostExecute(WorkoutsWall.java:3420)
08-28 17:39:28.140: E/AndroidRuntime(26801):    at com.example.workoutlog.WorkoutsWall$GetUserPicture.onPostExecute(WorkoutsWall.java:1)
08-28 17:39:28.140: E/AndroidRuntime(26801):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
08-28 17:39:28.140: E/AndroidRuntime(26801):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
08-28 17:39:28.140: E/AndroidRuntime(26801):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
08-28 17:39:28.140: E/AndroidRuntime(26801):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-28 17:39:28.140: E/AndroidRuntime(26801):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-28 17:39:28.140: E/AndroidRuntime(26801):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5226)
08-28 17:39:28.140: E/AndroidRuntime(26801):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 17:39:28.140: E/AndroidRuntime(26801):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-28 17:39:28.140: E/AndroidRuntime(26801):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
08-28 17:39:28.140: E/AndroidRuntime(26801):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
08-28 17:39:28.140: E/AndroidRuntime(26801):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The strange thing is that before this lines i have this code:

```
Log.i("name1", userProfilePictures[positionForPicture][0]);
```

Which giving me the string and not null error.

Why i get null pointer exception? Its the same string...

Comment: Data stored in array `userProfilePictures[positionForPicture][0]` appears to be null.

Comment: So why i get none null string when i run this code?

Log.i("name1", userProfilePictures[positionForPicture][0]);

Comment: In `new GetUserPicture().execute();`, do you do some processing that may alter the content of `userProfilePictures`?

Comment: @jbihan thanks you, i saw now my error...

Comment: Great then ! Maybe you could post your solution so other people can benefit from it ?

Answer (score 0):

if this async task is loading your array `userProfilePictures` you should wait for the answer. 
return a boolean in the postexecute and do:

```
Boolean b= new GetUserPicture().execute();
```